# Does python have a built-in function for interleaving generators/sequences?

Tags: python, functional-programming, python-itertools

I noticed that `itertools` does not (it seems to me) have a function capable of interleaving elements from several other iterable objects (as opposed to zipping them):

```
def leaf(*args): return (it.next() for it in cycle(imap(chain,args)))
tuple(leaf(['Johann', 'Sebastian', 'Bach'], repeat(' '))) => ('Johann', ' ', 'Sebastian', ' ', 'Bach', ' ')
```

(Edit) The reason I ask is because I want to avoid unnecessary zip/flatten occurrences.

Obviously, the definition of `leaf` is simple enough, but if there is a predefined function that does the same thing, I would prefer to use that, or a very clear generator expression. **Is there such a function built-in, in itertools, or in some other well-known library, or a suitable idiomatic expression?**

Edit 2: An even more concise definition is possible (using the `functional` package):

```
from itertools import *
from functional import *

compose_mult = partial(reduce, compose)
leaf = compose_mult((partial(imap, next), cycle, partial(imap, chain), lambda *args: args))
```

Comment: In a totally unrelated note I can't help but mention that the Bach in question was Johann, not John.

Comment: @9000: Quite - this fell out of a unit test where I absentmindedly wrote it as it is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The itertools [roundrobin() recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) would've been my first choice, though in your exact example it would produce an infinite sequence, as it stops with the longest iterable, not the shortest. Of course, it would be easy to fix that. Maybe it's worth checking out for a different approach?

Comment: That's the sort of thing I was thinking, except that (a) I prefer the leaf semantics (b) my definition is more concise.

Answer (score 17):

You're looking for the built-in [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the result:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(zip(['Johann', 'Sebastian', 'Bach'], itertools.repeat(' ')))
[('Johann', ' '), ('Sebastian', ' '), ('Bach', ' ')]
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(_))
['Johann', ' ', 'Sebastian', ' ', 'Bach', ' ']
```

Note that I used `list` just to force a nice output. Using the standard itertools, alternative implementations for `leaf` would be:

```
leaf = lambda *a: itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip(*a)) # Python 2.x
leaf = lambda *a: itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*a))            # Python 3.x
```

Comment: @larsmans Safer in what way? `itertools.izip` has been removed from Python since 3.0.

Comment: Okay. I still live in the Python 2.x world mostly.

Comment: Right, but that still introduces a zip, and then flattens the zipped pairs. My whole motivation (which I should have stated) was to avoid doing that.

Comment: @Marcin What is your problem with zipping and then flattening?

Comment: Speaking for @Marcin, imagine that the input iterables are huge or infinite and he'd probably rather process them iteratively rather than all at once.

Comment: @KirkStrauser Huh? Both `zip` (in Python 2 `itertools.izip`) and `chain.from_iterable` return generators and work fine with huge or infinite inputs.

Comment: @ phihag @KirkStrauser: The answer is that it's an unnecessary set of operations (boxing and unboxing in the tuples), and in larger expressions, it makes one more thing to understand.

Comment: @Marcin Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with *boxing and unboxing*. The memory consumption of the solution is in O(1), so it can't  be the allocation of memory.

Comment: @phihag: Are you really saying that zipping involves no memory allocation?

Comment: @phihag: Even if a sufficiently optimising compiler is able to consume  only one tuple's worth of memory, there will be an unnecessary roundtrip through the tuple constructor, unless the compiler is able to completely optimise it away.

Answer (score 2):

This custom function interleaves iterators and continues untill every iterator is exausted

```py
def interleave_iterators(*iterators):
    finished = [False for x in range(len(iterators))]
    stop_cond = functools.reduce(lambda x,y:not x or not y,finished)
    while stop_cond:
        for i,it in enumerate(iterators):
            try:
                yield next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                finished[i] = True
        stop_cond = functools.reduce(lambda x,y:not x or not y,finished)
```

For example

```py
it1 = iter([2,4,6,8])
it2 = iter([1,3,5,7,9,11,13])
for x in interleave_iterators(it1,it2): # prints 2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7 9 11 13
    print(str(x),end=" ")
```