# How to interleave two iterators where x% of the samples come from one iterator, and (1-x)% come from the other

Tags: python, iterator

Say that there are two iterators:

```
def genA():
    while True:
        yield 1

def genB():
    while True:
        yield 2

gA = genA()
gB = genB()
```

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8770796/3259896) they can be ***evenly*** interleaved using the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def cycle(iterable):
    # cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D A B C D ...
    saved = []
    for element in iterable:
        yield element
        saved.append(element)
    while saved:
        for element in saved:
              yield element

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))

aa = roundrobin(gA, gB)
next(aa)
```

So `next(aa)` will shift the iterator output each time, so a bunch of `next` calls will result in  `1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1` - `50%` will come from one iterator, and the other `50%` will come from the other.

I am wondering how we can code it so that `x%` will come from one iterator, and `(1-x)%` from the other. For example, `75%` from the first iterator, and `25%` from the other.

So several calls to `next(combinedIterator)` will result in something like this:

```
1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2
```

For my purpose, it doesn't matter if the output is strictly ordered like above, or if it is random, with the output determined by probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with a deterministic approach (as I understand from your self-answer), you can add an argument which is the percentage of the first iterator and then just calculate each iterator's "part". For example, if you want `.75` from the first iterator - this translates to: *for every **three** elements from `iterator1`, yield **one** element from `iterator2`*.

```py
def interleave(itt1, itt2, itt1_per):
    itt1_frac, total = itt1_per.as_integer_ratio()
    itt2_frac = total - itt1_frac
    while True:
        for _ in range(itt1_frac):
            yield next(itt1)
        for _ in range(itt2_frac):
            yield next(itt2)

newGen = interleave(gA, gB, .75)

for _ in range(12):
    print(next(newGen), end=' ')
```

This will print:

```
1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2
```

---

***Watch out!*** This will only work well for "nice" fractions. For example: using this function with `.6` means that *for every **`5,404,319,552,844,595`** elements from `iterator1`, it will yield **`3,602,879,701,896,397`** elements from `iterator2`*.

***One way to overcome this*** is to use [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) with ***[string arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755444/why-is-the-precision-accurate-when-decimal-takes-in-a-string-instead-of-float)***:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

def interleave(itt1, itt2, itt1_per):
    itt1_frac, total = Decimal(str(itt1_per)).as_integer_ratio()
    ...
```

Using `Decimal` now means that passing `.6` translates to the more **sensible**: *for every **three** elements from `iterator1`, yield **two** elements from `iterator2`*.

Using this revised code with `.6` as an argument, will print:

```
1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def genA():
    while True:
        yield 1

def genB():
    while True:
        yield 2

gA = genA()
gB = genB()

import random

def xyz(itt1, itt2):
    while True:
        if random.random() < .25:
            yield next(itt1)
        else:
            yield next(itt2)

newGen = xyz(gA, gB)

next(newGen)
```

This works for a uniform distribution. I won't select this as an answer for someone to possibility give a non probabilistic answer.